# App freezes and restarts when I swipe to a specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment called genreFragment, which has a recyclerview which displays a list of songs genres in the device. The problem started when I tried to implement multi-select feature for this recyclerview, whenever I switch to this fragment the app freezes and restarts.
And when I remove the lines in the fragment `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`  which sets the recyclerview's adapter to the recyclerview, or this line `genresList.add(genreModel);` the app doesn't freeze.

```
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import recyclerview_adapters.genres_adapter;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link genreFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link genreFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class genreFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    // true by default until content provider and recyclerview adapter is ready
    private final boolean no_content = true;

    private TextView nocontnet_text;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private List<GenreModel> genresList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<GenreModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

    onGenreLongClickListener mOnGenreLongClickListener;
    onClickWhileMultiSelectOn mOnClickWhileMultiSelectOn;

    boolean isMultiSelectOn = false;
    boolean selected = false;
    int c = 0;

    genres_adapter adapter;

/* IGNORE
    public genreFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment genreFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static genreFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        genreFragment fragment = new genreFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
*/
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_genre, container, false);

        nocontnet_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nocontent_genres);
       //initRecyclerView(view);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_genres);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new genres_adapter(genresList);
// Here I set the clicklisteners and onlongclicklisteners for the recyclerview 
            adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(isMultiSelectOn){
                        int position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
                        GenreModel genreModel = genresList.get(position);
                        selected = genreModel.isSelected();
                        if(selected){
                            genreModel.setSelected(false);
                            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            ImageView menu = view.findViewById(R.id.ac_more_playlists);
                            menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mOnClickWhileMultiSelectOn.onClick(genreModel, position, true);
                        }
                        else{
                            genreModel.setSelected(true);
                            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            ImageView menu = view.findViewById(R.id.ac_more_playlists);
                            menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mOnClickWhileMultiSelectOn.onClick(genreModel, position, false);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        int position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
                        GenreModel genreModel = genresList.get(position);
                        String genreName = genreModel.getName();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), genreActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("genre", genreName);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
            adapter.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    if(isMultiSelectOn){
                        int position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
                        GenreModel genreModel = genresList.get(position);
                        selected = genreModel.isSelected();
                        if(selected){
                            genreModel.setSelected(false);
                            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            ImageView menu = view.findViewById(R.id.ac_more_playlists);
                            menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mOnGenreLongClickListener.onLongClick(genreModel, position, true);
                        }
                        else{
                            genreModel.setSelected(true);
                            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            ImageView menu = view.findViewById(R.id.ac_more_playlists);
                            menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mOnGenreLongClickListener.onLongClick(genreModel, position, false);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        int position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
                        GenreModel genreModel = genresList.get(position);
                        genreModel.setSelected(true);
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        ImageView menu = view.findViewById(R.id.ac_more_playlists);
                        menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        isMultiSelectOn = true;
                        mOnGenreLongClickListener.onLongClick(genreModel, position, false);
                    }

              /* An interface I use to commuincate between the main activity and the fragments  ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setInterface(new clearSelectedRecyclerView() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTracksClear() {
                        //IGNORED
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAlbumsClear() {
                        //IGNORED
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onArtistsClear() {
                        //IGNORED
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onGenresClear() {
                        clearSelectedGenres(adapter, genresList);
                        isMultiSelectOn = false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPlaylistsClear() {
                        //IGNORED
                    }
                });
                */
                return true;
            }
        });


       // The problem happens in this line
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
/*IGNORE
            int exPermissionCheck = sharedPreferences.getInt("exPermissionCheck", PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED);
           if(exPermissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                getGenresList();
                if(genresList.size() > 0){
                    nocontnet_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else{
                    nocontnet_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
            else{
                nocontnet_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            return view;
*/
        }



    public void getGenresList(){
        ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

        if((cursor != null) && (cursor.moveToFirst())){

            int genre_column  = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME);
            int id_column = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID);

            do{
                String genreName = cursor.getString(genre_column);
                long id = cursor.getLong(id_column);

               GenreModel genreModel = new GenreModel();
                genreModel.setName(genreName);
                genreModel.setID(id);
                // The app also doesn't freeze when I remove this line which ads a new  element to the list attached to the adapter
                genresList.add(genreModel);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
             //
        }
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
        mOnGenreLongClickListener = (onGenreLongClickListener) getActivity();
        mOnClickWhileMultiSelectOn = (onClickWhileMultiSelectOn) getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        genresList.clear();
    }

    interface onGenreLongClickListener{
        void onLongClick(GenreModel genreModel, int position, boolean selected);
    }
    interface onClickWhileMultiSelectOn{
        void onClick(GenreModel genreModel, int position, boolean selected);
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    private void clearSelectedGenres(genres_adapter adapter, List<GenreModel> genres){
        GenreModel genreModel;
        for(int i = 0; i < genres.size(); i++){
            genreModel = genres.get(i);
            if(genreModel.isSelected)
                genreModel.setSelected(false);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This is the recyclerview's adapter class

```
public class genres_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<genres_adapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<GenreModel> genresList;
String genreName;
private Context context;
boolean isSelected = false;

private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;
private View.OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener;

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView gn_tv;
    ImageView menuButton;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        gn_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_name);
        menuButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ac_more_playlists);
    }
    View getItemView(){
        return itemView;
    }
}

public genres_adapter(List<GenreModel> genresList){
    this.genresList = genresList;
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener callback){
    this.mOnClickListener = callback;
}

public void setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener callback){
    this.mOnLongClickListener = callback;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rec_playlist_main, parent, false);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mOnClickListener.onClick(view);
        }
    });
    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(mOnLongClickListener);
    context = itemView.getContext();
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    View itemView;
     GenreModel genreModel = genresList.get(position);
     isSelected = genreModel.isSelected();
     genreName = genreModel.getName();
     holder.gn_tv.setText(genreName);

    holder.menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, holder.menuButton);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.item_menu);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.play_audio:
                            break;
                        case R.id.play_next:

                            break;
                        case R.id.add_toqueue:

                            break;
                        case R.id.add_toplaylist:

                            break;
                        case R.id.delete_track:

                            break;
                        case R.id.edit_info:

                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popupMenu.show();
        }

    });
    if(isSelected){
        holder.menuButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        itemView = holder.getItemView();
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else{
        holder.menuButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        itemView = holder.getItemView();
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return genresList.size();
}
}
```

recyclerview item model class

```
public class GenreModel {
String genreName;
long genreID;
boolean isSelected = false;

public String getName(){
    return genreName;
}

public long getID(){
    return genreID;
}
public boolean isSelected(){
    return isSelected();
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.genreName = name;
}

public void setID(long id){
    this.genreID = id;
}

public void setSelected(boolean isSelected){
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}
}
```

This is what I get in the logcat, apparently there is a memory leak, but I havent figured out where it could be.

```
  02-12 19:36:00.612 16860-16860/com.sparidapps.musicplayer E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                                                                            java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 48203392 byte allocation with 16749088 free bytes and 31MB until OOM
```

So my question is what causes this memory leak that freezes the app? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is black screen coming when launches the fragment ??

Comment: @Abhishek kumar  No the screen just freezes while still in the previous fragment for 3-4 secs and the app restarts.

Comment: It means you are handling data larger than the capicity of android.

Comment: Yes but I don't know from where these data comes from, I don't use any bitmaps and the list im handling consists of just 2 elements and other fragments with recyclerview in the activity don't have the same problem. @Abhishek kumar

Comment: What is the size of list @Tarek

Comment: It's supposedly 2, but since the app freezes when the first element is added it's size is only 1. @Abhishek kumar

Comment: This type of error comes when you will send / pass data higher than 1 MB its may be pojo classes, images, video , audio file.